# How to create icons for different screen densities putting minimum effort

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that similar questions were asked before but none of the answers satisfied me.

I want to put minimum effort in creating icons for different screen densities for my app. How can I achieve that?

Can I just create icon for the maximum screen density I want to support and downscale that image (following the scale ratios mentioned in Android-Iconography guide)? Is this that easy? Does this solution carry any implications?

Or maybe correct approach is to create vector graphics and then generate proper icons?

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be pixerl-perfect you'll have to create a vector image first. Then generate a raster image for each of the densities that you are planning to support. After that you'll have to tweak each of the raster images by hand  (to avoid things like disappearances of small details in the images for lower densities).